# Delphi package not Loading when i start Delphi

Tags: delphi, package, components, delphi-2009, bpl

I was working on my own package. Then while i was processing i wrongly click on the message *"**Don't load this package on the next start of Delphi**"*...

Even i uninstall, clean my package... After i recompile and reinstall it successfully : Delphi show me the message that my components been **compiled and registered successfully** (Some new components been identified and added : TMyComponents).

I was "hoping" when i will load my testing project again my component will still be there on my form but i get the message that ***"Classes TMyComponent not found. Ignore error and continue ? Note : this could delete the component or lost properties values"***

Then i check in the menu : **"Component / Installing Package"**, my package appear in the list but it's *"unchecked"*. If i check it manualy and load my project, my component is there, all is ok. if i restart delphi the package remain unchecked again and **still disabled**.

How can i re-activate this package to be load when i start Delphi as usual ?
*(Delphi-2009)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found something while i was searching in windows registry (Regedt32.exe):

**1 - I make sure that my package is in here** : 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\ **Known Packages**\
    "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl\MyPackage.bpl"

**2 - Then i deleted my package** from here
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\ **Disabled Packages**\
    "C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\6.0\Bpl\MyPackage.bpl"

**3 - i uninstall and reinstall** my package.

Now it works again

Comment: You don't need to declare the package to be known. That gets done for you when you install the package. Step 1 is redundant. The key is step 2.

Comment: Also make sure the test project has not added the package to the `Excluded_Packages` field of its `.dproj` file.

Comment: This worked for me too, except in D7 the key is here:  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Disabled Packages\. I had an error with one of my packages and I think I accidentally clicked "No" to the prompt do you want to load this package next time. Normally one could just manually re-install the packages and it would work fine but, possibly new for Win10, I had to manually delete them from this Disabled Packages registry key.

Answer (score 3):

This information is held in the registry. For Delphi 2009 look in:

```
HKCU\Software\CodeGear\BDS\6.0\Disabled Packages
```

Your package should be listed there. Delete the value for your package, and restart Delphi.